# Search the sentence in large text sentence corpus

Tags: string, algorithm, text

I am a beginner and I want to know if there's way to search a text sentence in a large text sequence of data (say 1 million) and search accordingly like when a user type:

> I shouldn't be there

then it should search for sequence like this:

> I should not be there

similar like this :

> I gonna go there.

to

> I going to go there.

I have been thinking for couple of days to figure out solution of this
problem.

If you know anything about how to deal with this problem then please provide a solution or just a hint would be more than enough. Thank you.

Comment: Not without deep knowledge of the language. What's the expanded form of Romanian *"m-or vedea că nu-s"*?

Comment: I just want to build for English language.

Comment: For English it depends on what kind of English you allow. Schoolbook English allows for a small and finite number of contractions (`x'll` expands to `x shall` or `x will`, `xn't` expands to `x not`, `I'm` expands to `I am`). You can then add `gonna` and `wanna`. Then search for the string as given *and* for the string with the contractions expanded.

Comment: It depends on the tool that you use. If you use Solr or Elastic Search, then yes, you can reach that, e.g. via synonyms.

Comment: Sounds a lot like natural language processing to me (at least the second example). It depends on the complexity of the what you want to achieve, but the second one is beyond the capabilities of synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly go trough both the sentence and text and replace all contractions with the long form. Then after that use Knuth-Morris-Pratt.